# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error tracing the origin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSDictionary *contactNameDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:item, @"contact", sortName, @"contactSortName", compositeName, @"compositeName", nil];
```

In what cases can this particular line of code generate EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

Comment: What are item, sortName, and compositeName? It will probably be one of those causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the objects are nil, you should get an Objective-C exception.

If any of the objects are garbage e.g. if they have been over-released, you should get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Use the Zombie tool to detect such issues.